# Using Google Sheets with ImportXML to get data from website

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get a list of entries from an XML file which is essentially an open data source.

**EDIT**:

If i use

```
=IMPORTXML(B1;”/*”)
```

all the content gets jammed into one cell. B1 is the field where the website URL is stored. What i would need in seperate columns are the title, the type, the city and the media objects.
The url:

```
http://meta.et4.de/rest.ashx/search/?experience=open-data-niedersachsen-tourismus&licensekey=VdEVEni8FhWA58234fIbjwk0bAysCkHhvXXTnC5b&type=POI&latitude=52.3744779&longitude=9.7385532&distance=30000&template=ET2014A_LIGHT_MULTI.xml
```

Looking forward to any idea, hint and answer.
Greetings

Comment: I can't see any `starts-with` attribute inside the code source!

Comment: @MikeSteelson i was looking for a fitting example and came across this one:
https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-sheets-for-web-scraping/415140/#close

I thought that part is essential to get a list of entries from the website but it didnt work for me.

Comment: thx for the tricks, I didn't know starts-with !

Comment: in your case, it will not work, and nothing will work with importxml (except title) because the site reloads after checking who is consulting. You can see that when you type the url in the address bar that a few seconds a message appears when you consult for the first time.

Comment: @MikeSteelson I see. I also got access to an XML file; maybe that changes something. I edited my question.

Comment: There is a namespace `xmlns="http://meta.et4.de/ET2014A_LIGHT_MULTI"`so you have to use local-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using importxml and xpath:

The site uses a namespace, so use local-name()

```
//*[local-name() ='title']  
//*[local-name() ='type']   
//*[local-name() ='city']
//*[local-name() ='media_objects']
```

a complex one to combine title/cities/media_object (/.. allow to get parents)

```
//*[local-name() ='media_object']/../../*[local-name() ='title']|//*[local-name() ='media_object']/../../*[local-name() ='city']|//*[local-name() ='media_object']/@*[local-name() ='source']|//*[local-name() ='media_object']/@*[local-name() ='url']
```

[image]

For default media, use these xpathes

```
//*[@*[local-name() = 'rel']='default']/../../*[local-name() ='title']  
//*[@*[local-name() = 'rel']='default']/../../*[local-name() ='city']   
//*[@*[local-name() = 'rel']='default']/./@*[local-name() ='source']    
//*[@*[local-name() = 'rel']='default']/./@*[local-name() ='url']
```

[image]

Comment: Thats what i was looking for! By the way, i am looking to sort the images per item a bit. How can i get a column only for the images that have rel="default" with them?
And i have a second column where all images per item should be grouped in one cell. I something like that possible?

Comment: I have completed my answer, take a new copy and see in Tabellenblatt5 (xpathes in blue, formulas in yellow) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jnqlo0RIopHYbNqXoBOHSB1y9XjnaVKRH56Myrlrxto/copy

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the title of that page, use:

> =IMPORTXML(B1,"//title", "en_US")

Which shows - for your page:

> POI

See here the [Google Sheet example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I2PCFWRIVVcB9X4U1RJ_V2fWJ-S2T_U9rtmGrKIr2T8/edit?usp=sharing).

I also think your formula has wrong quotes, that *might* be the reason you got that error.

If this is not the "title" you're trying to get, please, edit your question and explain which "title" = the value - you want to get.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It also actually started working when i replaced the commas with semicolons. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

### Using XmlService:

this is a completely different way, so I took the liberty of answering separately a second time

```
=parseXmlNamespace(A1)
```

with this script using namespace

```
function parseXmlNamespace(url) {
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  var nm = root.getNamespace();
  var result = [['title', 'city', 'media object', 'source', 'url']]
  var noeuds = root
    .getChildren('results', nm)[0]
    .getChildren('result', nm)[0]
    .getChildren('items', nm)[0]
    .getChildren('item', nm);
  noeuds.forEach(item => {
    try {
      item.getChildren('media_objects', nm)[0].getChildren('media_object', nm).forEach(it => {
        result.push([
          item.getChildren('title', nm)[0].getText(),
          item.getChildren('city', nm)[0].getText(),
          it.getText(),
          it.getAttribute('source').getValue(),
          it.getAttribute('url').getValue()])
      })
    } catch (e) {
      result.push([
        item.getChildren('title', nm)[0].getText(),
        item.getChildren('city', nm)[0].getText(),
        '', '', ''])
    }
  })
  return result
}
```

[Class XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service)

[image]